# Fedora 31: "Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel for adding new hardware support to the system" in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, kernel, fedora-30

I'm using Fedora 31 and installed VirtualBox using RPM from the website (VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.14_140239_fedora31-1.x86_64.rpm), which should be the most recent version.

Starting it gives me the following error:

```
$ virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (5.8.11-100.fc31.x86_64) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

From the kernel-version everything seems to be fine though.

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.8.11-100.fc31.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 23 15:15:42 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And when I'm trying to start my Virtual Machines I'll get:

```
**Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)**

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

But the modules won't install:

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

Most pages refer to installing something like: [`sudo dnf install -y kernel-devel kernel-devel-$(uname -r)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369065/rhel-this-system-is-currently-not-set-up-to-build-kernel-modules)
but this gives me an error as the package can't be found.

I checked on some [VirtualBox-Forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=94330), dealing with Fedora.
They also recommend installing the headers, just with a slightly different command. Either it can't be found or it's installed already:

```
Das Paket kernel-headers-5.8.11-100.fc31.x86_64 ist bereits installiert.
No match for argument: kernel-devel-5.8.11-100.fc31.x86_64
Fehler: Es konnte kein Treffer gefunden werden.: kernel-devel-5.8.11-100.fc31.x86_64
```

In most Ubuntu Forums it seems the issue is somewhat quickly removed with the same command, just by apt-get. Sometimes it's claimed the packages would be outdated, but as Fedora is updated more frequent than Ubuntu I wonder what's the problem behind it.

Comment: Try this article below to see if it helps.   https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-fedora/

Comment: If secure boot is enabled, you will need to [sign the kernel modules](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_Kernel_Modules/#sect-signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot) before they can be loaded.  `mokutil` can be used to enroll your `MOK` public key.  After enrolling my `MOK` (done once), I use a script (so I don't need to remember the details) to sign the kernel modules and then everything works fine.

Comment: @John that actually did solve it. Thank you

Comment: I posted as a solution for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an article for you to help install guest additions.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-fedora/

> The first step in the installation of VirtualBox guest additions is
> the installation of kernel headers. This includes the installation of
> the dkms package (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) alongside other build
> tools as shown.
>
> $ sudo dnf install dkms kernel-devel gcc bzip2 make curl
>
> Once you have successfully installed kernel headers, you need to
> confirm the version of the Linux kernel and ensure it matches the
> version of the just installed kernel headers.
>
> To check the version of the Linux kernel run the command.
>
> $ uname -r  OR $ hostnamectl | grep -i kernel
>
> To check the version of the kernel development tool (kernel-devel)
> execute.
>
> $ sudo rpm -qa kernel-devel
>
> Verify Linux Kernel Headers Verify Linux Kernel Headers
>
> If the versions of the two (kernel version and kernel-devel) do not
> match as shown in the screenshot above, update the kernel using the
> command.
>
> $ sudo dnf update kernel-*
>
> When you are done updating the kernel, reboot the system, and again,
> verify the kernel version again.
>
> $ uname -r

That has worked for you.  Many thanks, @John

Comment: I'm trying to understand. You give instructions for installing guest additions in a running VM, but the OP writes that no VM can be started. Is there a misunderstanding?

Comment: The answer in the information is to install Kernel Headers (which I used to have to do). Once done, the author has indicated "it worked" so then I assume the machine started and then also provided the added support once started. As noted, I used to have to do this myself,

Comment: I suppose the kernel module building requirements for VirtualBox installation on the host system (the OP's problem) are fortunately met by kernel module building requirements in the guest system for this specific instance. The OP may also want to review Oracle's VirtualBox installation guide.

Comment: @rickhg12hs - I too thought it was a misunderstanding. But it works. So I'm fine

Answer (score -1):

[This guide](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) helped me. VirtualBox became working smoothly at my Fedora 34. There is also a guide for Guest Additions install at the bottom of the VirtualBox install guide.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1065276)

Comment: @MMM I know. I wish I could have time.